# Unity 2 IDisposable Issue in Console Application C#

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using Unity 2.1.505.0 in a console application, which consists of an `IDisposable` implementation, `CarRepository`. However, the `Dispose()` is never called when out of its scope. Below is the code sample:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            CarShop.Entry();
        }
    }

    class CarShop
    {
       static UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        public static void Entry()
        {           
            unityContainer.RegisterType<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();
            var carShop = new CarShop();
            carShop.BuyCar();
        }

      public void BuyCar()
      {
          CheckCar();
      }

      private void CheckCar()
      {
          var carService = unityContainer.Resolve<CarService>();
          var car = carService.GetCar(1);  
         // **Dispose() method is not called out of this scope**
      }
    }

   class CarService
    {
        private ICarRepository carRepository;
        public CarService(ICarRepository carRepository)
        {
            this.carRepository = carRepository;
        }

        public Car GetCar(int id)
        {
            return this.carRepository.GetCar(id);
        }
    }

    interface ICarRepository
    {
        Car GetCar(int id);
    }

    class CarRepository : ICarRepository, IDisposable
    {
        public Car GetCar(int id)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void Dispose()  
        {

        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
    }
```

Any idea??

**Update**

As @nemesv suggests the solution below:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<ICarRepository, CarRepository>(
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())

 using (var childContainer = unityContainer.CreateChildContainer())
    {
        var carService = childContainer.Resolve<CarService>();
        var car = carService.GetCar(1);            
    }
```

It works. But unlike `Unity.MVC`, it requires explicit creation of `childContainer`. Is there transparent way of dispose of `IDispose` object, like Unity.MVC. Or other tools in the future.

Comment: Dispose is NEVER called automatically, it has nothing to do with Unity.

Comment: Unity.MVC can solve the problem. So I think it will for console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RegisterType` method by default uses the `TransientLifetimeManager` which does not store a reference to the created objects so it does not call the `Dispose` for you.

Among the built `LifetimeManager` implementations only the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` disposes the managed objects when the container itself is disposed.

You can read about the Lifetime Managers here: [Understanding Lifetime Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

If your goal is to dispose the `CarRepository` after an usage then you can achieve it with using the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` and [child containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660895%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx):

```
public static void Entry()
{           
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ICarRepository, CarRepository>(
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    var carShop = new CarShop();
    carShop.BuyCar();
}

private void CheckCar()
{
    using (var childContainer = unityContainer.CreateChildContainer())
    {
        var carService = childContainer.Resolve<CarService>();
        var car = carService.GetCar(1);            
    }
    // **Dispose() method is not called out of this scope**
}
```

Comment: The ContainerControlledLifetimeManager is not working. Am I missing something else?

Comment: What do you mean on "ContainerControlledLifetimeManager  is not working"?

Comment: By "ContainerControlledLifetimeManager is not working" I meant the dispose() is not called.

Comment: I wrote that "ContainerControlledLifetimeManager disposes the managed objects **when the container itself is disposed.**" so I never wrote that it will work for you because you don't dispose your container. See my updated answer for a solution using `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`

Comment: That works. But unlike Unity.MVC, it requires explicit creation of childContainer. Is there transparent way of dispose of IDispose object, like Unity.MVC. Or other tools.

Comment: No. Unity.MVC also creates and manages an explicit childContainer and disposes it at the end of request. But it is done by the `UnityDependecyResolver` so it hidden from you.